# Using file globbing for the echo command in bash

Tags: bash, echo, glob

what I want to do something like this: `echo "foo" > bar/**/buzz` but this is not valid

basically, I want to echo a string into a file in every directory in bar.

I'm sure there is a simple way of doing this lol.

Comment: Do these `buzz` files already exist? Your command won't work otherwise (as globs match actual filesystem contents).

Comment: Yeah they would exist

Comment: Okay, great, then; the previously-added answer should work. (I'm 95% sure the question already exists elsewhere in the knowledgebase, which is why I answered community-wiki, since it's not kosher to get rep points for answering a duplicate; haven't found the earlier instance yet, though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File descriptors can only point one place at a time, so using a glob (that isn't guaranteed to match exactly one file) as the target of one *directly* doesn't make sense. However, that one place can be the stdin of a program that copies to multiple destinations, as `tee` does when given multiple filenames as arguments:

```
echo "foo" | tee bar/**/buzz >/dev/null
```